# Got NoMethodError while parsing yaml

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a YAML file like that:

```
--- 
name:    dummy
version: 0.2.0
title:   dummy
summary: dummy
```

Now I tried to get the version number:

```
config = YAML.load_file('Index.yml')
oldversion = config[0]['version']
```

Why do it get the following error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
config = YAML.load_file('Index.yml')
oldversion = config['version']
```

Answer (score 1):

With `config[0]` you are indexing a sequence/array, and at the top level of your yaml file you have a mapping, not a sequence, so leave that out: `oldversion = config['version']` or change your YAML file to:

```
--- 
- name:    dummy
  version: 0.2.0
  title:   dummy
  summary: dummy
```

if you eventually want a list of such objects (with `name`, `version`, etc.) in your configuration.